# How do I get the value of get() function

Tags: php, oop

Sorry I am still beginner in Object oriented PHP. 
I want to ask if how do I get the data from get() function on my class.db.php in my index.page

class.db.php

```
    public function get($table, $where){
        return $this->action('Select *', $table, $where);
}
```

Index.php what script do I put to retrieve the data?????

Comment: `$yourclass->get('table', 'where');`?

Answer (score -2):

you need to make the object of the class in order to call its function

```
class myclass {
  public function get($table, $where){
        return $this->action('Select *', $table, $where);
}

}

$table=htmlspecialchars($_POST['table']);
$where=htmlspecialchars($_POST['where']);
$obj=new myclass();

$var=$obj->get($table, $where);
```

Comment: Thank you! do u have sample?

Comment: That won't work because the `get` method is inside a class and OP wants to retrieve it from outside the class.

Comment: "in my index page" and you refer to `$this` which should **not** be used as a class instance - it should only be used to refer to "this class instance". The correct code is `$db = new db(); $db->get('table', 'where');`.

Comment: ok! i thought he is trying to call the function within same class! i know that for calling the function outside class he needs to make an object or assign the method static

Comment: sorry I am still learning, I will do your suggestion. thank you all

Comment: @Jayson Lacson edited my answer, this will help you!

Comment: @sunny this is not clear to me. $var=$obj->get($table, $where); and how do I post the data?

Comment: @JaysonLacson By putting your table name instead of `$table` and your where query instead of `$where`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is what i did $agent = new Agent(); 
$agent->get('agent', "where `id='$id' "); is it correct?

Comment: @JaysonLacson It depends. You're pasting a variable directly into your query allowing for SQL injection. You should rather use prepared statements and bind variables. Let me paste our "usual" help for people using the `mysql_` functions (which it isn't clear if you do or not):

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).